Film about a family whose house is occupied by soldiers?
I once saw a film about a Palestinian Family whose house was occupied by Israeli soldiers. I can't remember much else about the film, does anyone know what it was called?

Little help? What is the time frame of the movie? How long ago did you see it? English language or ?? Give us some more here, please.

The movie is about 6-7 years old, it was set in modern times. The family live in a remote part of Palestine, the family is normal but one day Israeli soldiers turn up and take over the top part of the house for a period of time and this causes strain in the family as the father of the house tries to keep the family together. I think it was in Arabic, I might be mistaken.

The film is called "Private", by Saverio Costanzo, shot in 2004.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_%28film%29

I hope it was the film and not the director that was shot in 2004...
